# How do you have different server execution based on selected tabItem() in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, module, shinyapps, golem

**Background**
I am using {brochure} and {golem} to build a shiny app. I have one outer module `grid` that consists of inner modules `subGrid2` which displays the same module UI on two tabs.

**GOAL**

- have a module `subGrid2` that can be used for repeating graph
  visualizations on multiple tabs.
- in the REPREX --> fake graph generated from {shinipsum} to
  be displayed on the "Home" tab + "Portfolio" tab
- use `observeEvent` to look at the slected tab and generate server response respectivley

**Problem**

The `observeEvent` reactive expr. fails to recognize when the corresponding tab is selected to generate the correct server response.

*-using the reprex below replicates my issue-*

**TL/DR**

1. Why wont the `observeEvent` reactive generate the correct server response per the selected tab?

**REPREX**

uncomment `observeEvent` to see error

```
#22.2.22
library(brochure)

library(shiny)

library(shinipsum)

library(shinydashboard)

library(shinydashboardPlus)

mod_subGrid2_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)
    tagList(
        plotOutput(ns("plot"))
    )
}

mod_subGrid2_server <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        ns <- session$ns

        output$plot <- renderPlot({
            shinipsum::random_ggplot()
        })
    })
}

#Setup dashboard

mod_Grid_ui <- function(id) {
    ns <- NS(id)

    shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage(
        skin = "midnight",
        header = dashboardHeader(title = "test"),
        sidebar = dashboardSidebar(
            shinydashboard::sidebarMenu(
                # Setting id makes input$tabs give the tabName of currently-selected tab
                id = "tabs",
                menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("tachometer-alt")),
                menuItem("Portfolio", tabName = "portfolio", icon = icon("chart-line"), badgeLabel = "new",
                         badgeColor = "green")
            )
        ),

        body = shinydashboard::dashboardBody(
            # Enable shinyjs
            shinyjs::useShinyjs(),

            shinydashboard::tabItems(
                shinydashboard::tabItem("home",
                                        shiny::tagList(
                                            div(p("Content for 1st tab goes here -- GRID MODULE")),
                                            mod_subGrid2_ui(ns("subGrid2_ui_1"))
                                        )
                ),
                shinydashboard::tabItem("portfolio",
                                        shiny::tagList(
                                            div(p("Content for 2nd goes here -- GRID MODULE (2x)")),
                                            titlePanel(title = "The same module UI goes here"),

mod_subGrid2_ui(ns("subGrid2_ui_2"))
                                        )
                )
            )
        )
    )
}

mod_Grid_server <- function(id) {
    moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
        ns <- session$ns
        mod_subGrid2_server("subGrid2_ui_1")
        mod_subGrid2_server("subGrid2_ui_2")

       ## uncomment to try
        # observeEvent(input$tabs,{
        #   if(input$tabs == "home"){
        #     # <subGrid> server fragment
        #     mod_subGrid2_server("subGrid2_ui_1")
        #   } else if(input$tabs == "portfolio"){
        #     mod_subGrid2_server("subGrid2_ui_1")
        #   }
        # }, ignoreNULL = TRUE, ignoreInit = TRUE)
    })
}

brochureApp(
    page(
        href = "/",
        ui = tagList(
            mod_Grid_ui("grid_1")
        ),
        server = function(input, output, session) {
            mod_Grid_server("grid_1")
        }
    ),
    wrapped = shiny::tagList
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a module nested inside another module, you need to ns() the id of the nested UI function.
So here, `mod_subGrid2_ui(ns("subGrid2_ui_1"))`.

Here is a minimal reprex:

```r
mod_subGrid2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    plotOutput(ns("plot"))
  )
}

mod_subGrid2_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      shinipsum::random_ggplot()
    })
  })
}

mod_Grid_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    mod_subGrid2_ui(ns("subGrid2_ui_1"))
  )
}

mod_Grid_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    mod_subGrid2_server("subGrid2_ui_1")
  })
}

brochureApp(
  page(
    href = "/",
    ui = tagList(
      mod_Grid_ui("grid_1")
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
      mod_Grid_server("grid_1")
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Sorry, the reprex throws an error and can't be launched on my laptop, so I'm trying to guess, as there are a lot of code :) 
You need to ns() the modules that are inside other module, so mod_subGrid2_server(ns("subGrid2_ui_1")). See my updated answer.

Comment: That seem to have solved the issue for me! Am I correct in assuming that the server module does not need to be ns() as namespacing is implicit?

https://mastering-shiny.org/scaling-modules.html#namespacing

Comment: There is also no more use for ` ui = function(request) { mod_dashboard_ui(id = id) }`? as that logic is implied with the module correct?

Comment: @JJFantini there is no need to namespace the server id indeed, it's done under the hood by shiny. For the ui = function(request){}, it depends on wether you want to ui to be rendered __at application runtime__ (i.e the function is run every time a user connect) or __at application launch__ (i.e when you call brochureApp() in your R session).

Comment: I have updated question to better reflect the problem.